# Kotlin coroutines "happens-before" guarantees?

Tags: kotlin, concurrency, kotlin-coroutines, happens-before

Do Kotlin coroutines provide any "happens-before" guarantees?

For example, is there "happens-before" guarantee between write to `mutableVar` and subsequent read on (potentially) other thread in this case:

```
suspend fun doSomething() {
    var mutableVar = 0
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        mutableVar = 1
    }
    System.out.println("value: $mutableVar")
}
```

Edit:

Maybe additional example will clarify the question better becuase it's more Kotlin-ish (except for mutability). Is this code thread-safe:

```
suspend fun doSomething() {
    var data = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        Data(1)
    }
    System.out.println("value: ${data.data}")
}

private data class Data(var data: Int)
```

Comment: Note that when running on the JVM Kotlin uses the same memory model as Java.

Comment: @Slaw , I know that. However, there is a lot of magic going on under the hood. Therefore, I'd like to understand whether there are any happens-before guarantees that I get from coroutines, or it's all on me.

Comment: If anything, your second example presents an even simpler scenario: it just uses an object created within `withContext`, whereas the 1st example creates it first, mutates within `withContext`, and then reads after `withContext`. So the 1st example exercises more thread safety features.

Comment: ...and both examples exercise just the "program order" aspect of happens-before, the most trivial one. I'm speaking on the level of coroutines here, not the underlying JVM. So basically, you're asking whether or not Kotlin coroutines are so severely broken that they don't even provide program order happens-before.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, correct me if I'm wrong, but JLS only guarantees "program order happens-before" for execution on the same thread. Now, with coroutines, even though the code looks sequential, in practice there is some machinery that offloads it to different threads. 
I understand your point "this is such a basic guarantee that I wouldn't even waste my time checking it" (from another comment), but I asked this question to get a rigorous answer. I'm pretty sure that the examples I wrote are thread safe, but I want to understand why.

Comment: You have to think on the level of coroutines. On that level, you wrote sequential code involving a single coroutine (`withContext` just continues executing the same coroutine in a different context). So you're exercising nothing more than program-order consistency. Now, there are two concerns: 1. Do Kotlin coroutines guarantee program-order consistency? 2. Does the actual implementation uphold that guarantee? I'm not sure which of these two concerns you are suspicious about.

Answer (score 8):

The code you wrote has three accesses to shared state:

```
var mutableVar = 0                        // access 1, init
withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    mutableVar = 1                        // access 2, write
}
System.out.println("value: $mutableVar")  // access 3, read
```

The three accesses are strictly sequentially ordered, with no concurrency between them, and you can rest assured that Kotlin's infrastructure takes care of establishing a *happens-before* edge when handing off to the `IO` thread pool and back to your calling coroutine.

Here's an equivalent example that may perhaps look more convincing:

```
launch(Dispatchers.Default) {
    var mutableVar = 0             // 1
    delay(1)
    mutableVar = 1                 // 2
    delay(1)
    println("value: $mutableVar")  // 3
}
```

Since `delay` is a suspendable function, and since we're using the `Default` dispatcher that is backed by a thread pool, lines 1, 2 and 3 may each execute on a different thread. Therefore your question about *happen-before* guarantees applies equally to this example. On the other hand, in this case it is (I would hope) completely obvious that the behavior of this code is consistent with the principles of sequential execution.

Roman Elizarov, the primary author of Kotlin Coroutines, makes the same points in a [blog post](https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292). Relevant quote:

> Even though a coroutine in Kotlin can execute on multiple threads, it is just like a thread from a standpoint of mutable state. No two actions in the same coroutine can be concurrent.

Comment: Thanks. It's actually the part after "rest assured" that motivated me to ask this question. Are there any links to docs that I could read? Alternatively, links to source code where this happens-before edge is established would also be of great help (join, synchronization, or any other method).

Comment: @Vasiliy The [documentation of `withContext`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/with-context.html) says it will "_suspend until it completes_". That implies a _happens-before_ relationship.

Comment: This is such a basic guarantee that I wouldn't even waste my time checking it. Under the hood it boils down to `executorService.submit()` and there is some typical mechanism of awaiting on the completion of the task (completing a `CompletableFuture` or something similar). From Kotlin coroutines' point of view there is no concurrency at all here.

Comment: You can think of your question as analogous to asking "does the OS guarantee a happens-before when suspending a thread and then resuming it on another core?" Threads are to coroutines what CPU cores are to threads.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. However, I asked this question to understand why it works. I see your point, but, so far, it's not the rigorous answer I'm looking for.

Comment: I think you're actually looking for something else than formal rigor because we have already established that your code is sequential and that Kotlin coroutines do, beyond any doubt, provide a happens-before guarantee to actions ordered by program order. Maybe you're looking for a conclusive proof that the implementation is not broken, but that's a pretty tall order, and something you'll have to keep re-evaluating with each new version of Kotlin.

Comment: Well... I actually don't think this thread has established that the code is sequential.  It has asserted it, surely.  I, too, would be interested in seeing the mechanism that guarantees that the example behaves as expected, without affecting performance.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike What do you think is missing? A link to the documentation on the semantics of `withContext`? Your second concern, the mechanism, is an implementation detail that has no bearing on the semantics. The mechanism is specific to each dispatcher, anyway.

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike `without affecting performance` -- _of course_ handing off to another thread and back affects performance, compared to just executing all the code without interruptions. Nobody disputes that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I haven't been able to find a definitive answer to this, with Kotlin coroutines or Java ExecutorService. Every example I've found is with a writable primitive variable. What about indirect members of an object? For example, if we replace `var mutableVar = 0` in your code with `val list = MutableList()` and `mutableVar = 1` with `list.add(1)`, and then print the size of the list in the last line of code, is there a guarantee that the entire state of the object is happens-before? Are all the members of the list effectively volatile?

Comment: @Tenfour04 They don't have to be volatile. There's a happen-before when entering `withContext`, and a happens-before when exiting it.

Comment: Does happens-before extend to all memory, even indirectly accessible members of members of objects?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Yes, that's how happens-before works, it's not defined by access chain but by a simple sequence of actions. All actions done by one thread happen-before each other in their program order. So, since `withContext` doesn't introduce any concurrency, all you need is those two happens-before edges that go from the initial carrier thread to the thread inside `withContext`, and then back from that to the initial thread. But `withContext` isn't even special here, every time a function suspends, it can awake in another thread, and everybody just assumes that works without issue.

Comment: "This is such a basic guarantee that I wouldn't even waste my time checking it." - I would disagree, it is very important to have a well-defined and specified "memory model"...

Comment: @snorbi Kotlin doesn't even have a full language specification, and we still all happily use it, because we mostly rely on the semantics provided by the Java specification (for example, details about number conversion). By comparison, this is one of the most obvious guarantees to assume.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the Kotlin language specification is fairly comprehensive: https://kotlinlang.org/spec/introduction.html

Comment: @snorbi Wow, definitely much improved since the list time I checked! But no chapter on the memory model. Even so, I don't think you need a memory model specification to be assured that that a coroutine can observe its own writes. Memory models exist to specify what happens under concurrent access, not sequential.

Comment: All the reasoning and references to JVM constructs should be deleted from this thread because it is very misleading. Kotlin and kotlinx-coroutines are multiplatform, and Kotlin/Native has _nothing_ to do with the JVM, so reasoning by using `ExecutorService` examples is just plain incorrect.

Comment: @snorbi In that case we'll just have to live with the fact that Kotlin doesn't have any memory model at all. Basically, all programs counting on happens-before at any place are broken.

Answer (score 4):

Coroutines in Kotlin do provide happens before guarantees.

The rule is: inside a coroutine, the code **prior** to a suspend function call **happens before** the code **after** the suspend call.

You should think about coroutines as if they were regular threads:

> Even though a coroutine in Kotlin can execute on multiple threads it is just like a thread from a standpoint of mutable state. No two actions in the same coroutine can be concurrent.

Source: https://proandroiddev.com/what-is-concurrent-access-to-mutable-state-f386e5cb8292

Getting back to the code example. Capturing vars in lambda function bodies is not ideal, especially when lambda is a coroutine. In fact,

> Capturing mutable variables (var) into the scope of such block is almost always an error

(a statement from KT-15514)

The code prior to a lambda does not happen before the code inside.

See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15514

Comment: The rule is this, actually: the code prior to a suspend function call _happens-before_ the code inside the suspend function, _happens-before_ the code after the suspend call. This, in turn, can be generalized to "the code's program order is also the code's _happens-before_ order". Note the absence of anything specific to suspendable functions in that statement.

Comment: @Marko Tololnik I don't think this is the case, have a look at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15514

Comment: I had a look, but I didn't get your point. It doesn't discuss the ordering of suspendable function calls.