# Get value from withTimeout

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm running a coroutine that is reading from a `receiverChannel`. I've got this coroutine wrapped within a timeout and I want to get the number of messages it managed to read before the timeout cancels it. Here's what I have:

```
runBlocking {    
    val receivedMessages = withTimeoutOrNull(someTimeout) {
        var found = 0
        while (isActive && found < expectedAmount){
            val message = incoming.receive()
            // some filtering
            found++
        }
        found
    } ?: 0 // <- to not have null...

    // Currently prints 0, but I want the messages it managed to read
    println("I've received $receivedMessages messages") 
}
```

I know I can use atomicInteger, but I would like to keep away from java specifics here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local variables in a coroutine don't need to be atomic because of the [happens-before guarantee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58518783/kotlin-coroutines-happens-before-guarantees) even though there may be some thread swapping going on. Your code doesn't have any parallelism, so you can use the following:

```
runBlocking {    
    var receivedMessages = 0
    withTimeoutOrNull(someTimeout) {
        while (isActive && receivedMessages < expectedAmount){
            val message = incoming.receive()
            // some filtering
            receivedMessages++
        }
    }

    println("I've received $receivedMessages messages") 
}
```

If you do have multiple children coroutines running in parallel, you can use a Mutex. [More info here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

Comment: good point. thanks