# Is this kotlin coroutine thread safe?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say, I have the function like this

```
fun myFun() {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            val state = mutableSetOf<Int>()

            for(x in 1.100) {
                // do something
                delay(100)
                // update state after delay resume
                state.add(x)
            }
        }
    }
```

Is the code above threadsafe? Because delay method can resume in any threads in Dispatchers.Default. Any thread can touch the state variable.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. There is only one coroutine, nothing that could be unsafe. If you are asking if you can safely update a `MutableState` from a coroutine, the answer is yes.

Comment: This code is not at all concurrent, but fully sequential. So yes, it's safe.

Comment: The reason is because delay method can resume in any thread in Dispatchers.Default

Comment: Yes, it can, but why is this a problem? Sets can be modified from multiple threads, just not at the same time.

Comment: @Jorn I would not say that. A coroutine implies potential context switches (supended/resumed). I think it is a legitimate question, but maybe lack some clarity (and it is not always simple to write a clear question about memory safety/context switching, etc.)

Comment: @broot but when it is modified by another thread, does this thread see the latest value in this case?

Comment: Yes, coroutines provide the happened-before guarantees when suspending and resuming.

Comment: Thanks @broot, I guess coroutines have to support it, but I want to confirm.

Comment: @broot You"re last comment is gold (and it is not ironic). That is a very important aspect of coroutines, and I personnally think it deserves to be an answer, not just a comment. Most users coming from java.concurrent world will have the same question, and it is not crystal clear if coroutines provide that safety (I haven't find the answer when browsing [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/shared-mutable-state-and-concurrency.html)

Comment: I guess this question is kind of a duplicate of this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58520801/1540818

Comment: @amanin Thank you :⁠-⁠) Yes, I agree, unfortunately official documentation for coroutines lacks such details. I can't verify this right now as I'm far from the computer, but I believe I didn't read this in docs, but either in Roman Elizarov's blog or one of KEEPs. This is really wrong